# Gnome settings only offers 49.99 Hz for a 60 Hz monitor

Tags: monitors, mutter

I have a 60 Hz monitor, but Gnome 40 settings only allows 49.99 Hz (and 29.99 Hz). I'm running Wayland, obviously.
[image: Gnome monitor settings with the refresh rate dropdown open, showing options 49,99 Hz and 29,99 Hz]

Why is that?

Gnome's animations don't feel smooth either, can that be related?

It's quite a big monitor with 3440 × 1440 px², and in another older question [How to force 60 Hz in 1366x768 despite kernel bug after kernel 4.13?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444055/how-to-force-60-hz-in-1366x768-despite-kernel-bug-after-kernel-4-13) it states that there's a kernel bug that limits refresh rate on high resolutions due to power savings with Xorg. Might this still be relevant and related?

I'm on a Lenovo T470s with Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02).

Comment: What does the EDID tell ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It says `# Monitor preferred modeline (60.0 Hz vsync, 66.7 kHz hsync, ratio 16/9, 157 dpi)`. The ModeLine seems rubbish, it’s set to FullHD. Also, the screen size in cm and inch is totally off. Also, the screen is 21:9, not 16:9. But this does not concern refresh rate.

Comment: So you mean the EDID is just broken. What does the Xorg.log tell when setting the display ?

Comment: I’m on Wayland. I believe there is no Xorg involved for quite a while now, is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the [Intel HD Graphics 620 on a Intel Core i7-7600U supports 4K only at 24 Hz via HDMI](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/97466/intel-core-i77600u-processor-4m-cache-up-to-3-90-ghz.html#bladeInside), and respectively the 3440 × 1440 px² at 50 Hz.

The specification mentions 4K at 60 Hz via Display Port, and if I understand correctly, the DP interface is the USB-C plug.

When connecting the same monitor on USB Type-C port (DisplayPort), with a HDMI adapter, 60 Hz are the default and available in the dropdown.

It’s quite counter-intuitive that there would be a difference.

Animations seem way smoother now on USB-C.