# Low refresh rate on Wayland

Tags: xorg, monitors, wayland

The highest refresh rate in my GNOME on Wayland in Fedora 34 (or GNOME on Wayland in Ubuntu) is 60.xx Hz, whereas it is 120.xx Hz in GNOME on Xorg. Why is this, and is there any way to enable the highest (120 Hz) refresh rate on Wayland or to at least increase it? The file `~/.config/monitors.xml` already contains the 120.xx Hz rate from Xorg.

There is a related question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/647431/gnome-settings-only-offers-49-99-hz-for-a-60-hz-monitor).

Comment: Distro? Compositor? There's no such thing as Wayland - it's just a protocol. It's like saying you've got 60fps in libX11.

Comment: Added the required information. I don't know what compositor GNOME uses, but I believe the window manager is Mutter. If I am not wrong, the situation will be the same on KDE. As far as I can tell, it does not really matter what it is; using Wayland on any desktop environment in any distro causes this. Hope this helps.